# web service is not running

Tags: web-services, deployment, jboss, wsdl

I am new to this WEB SERVICE concept so pardon me if I ask some stupid question. Here is what I am trying to do.

1) I have created a dynamic project in Eclipse with Jboss as App server with Dynamic web module version as 2.5

2) I have created a simple java class annotated @webService.

```
@WebService
public class SampleWebServiceExample {
public String getStringWebService(String a)
{
    return "Web Service is running with input: "+a;
}}
```

Now when I am deploying it service is getting deployed but I am not able to find my wsdl file. Heres is Jboss AS 7.1 server log

```
18:23:40,415 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) 

JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SampleWebService.war"
18:23:40,915 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-4) Add Service
 id=SampleWebServiceExample
 address=http://localhost:8090/SampleWebService/SampleWebServiceExample
 implementor=SampleWebServiceExample
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http:///}SampleWebServiceExampleService
 portName={http:///}SampleWebServiceExamplePort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false
18:23:41,261 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-4) Creating Service {http:///}SampleWebServiceExampleService from class SampleWebServiceExample
18:23:42,376 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8090/SampleWebService/SampleWebServiceExample
18:23:42,541 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher] (MSC service thread 1-4) WSDL published to: file:/D:/JavaWork/JBoss_AS/jboss-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/wsdl/SampleWebService.war/SampleWebServiceExampleService.wsdl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I got solution.JBoss AS keeps the generated wsdl files from EJBs with @Webservice annotation in the data folder. So if we want to access the wsdl we can access it as

```
http://localhost:8090/SampleWebService/SampleWebServiceImpl?wsdl
```

we can find the publish address from server log and add `?wsdl`... thats it :)